# How to get JSON id with button in tableview cell in swift4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm using `tableView` cell with button name of delete and I want to delete my JSON data from `tableView` cell I need to so That JSON ID to delete the JSON data from my `Tableview`. I'm using to get the JSON ID for that `indexPath` in `didSelect` row function. but the problem is I can't get JSON Id from that `indexPath` without pressing the row.

```
var selectedList: JSONList?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedList = JSONList[indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableviewCell

    cell?.Numbers.text = JSONList[indexPath.row].Number

    cell?.Trash.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Deleting), for: .touchUpInside)


    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell!
}

//here is my delete function calling

func Deleting() {

let selectedListObj = selectedList
    print(selectedListObj!.id)
}
```

Comment: use closure or delegate for getting the indexpath

Comment: Your naming is confusing. Is `JSONList` a type or a variable name (instance)? Please name types with capitalized names and variables and functions with lowercased names.

Comment: JSONList  is modal of json class

Comment: Then you cannot use `JSONList[indexPath.row]` because the index subscription requires an array.

Comment: i'm using as u say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set a tag to the button which it will be in your case the 
row of the `IndexPath`, add this code in `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell?.Trash.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleting(_:)), for: 
.touchUpInside)
cell?.Trash.tag = indexPath.row
```

You need to modify the `deleting()` function to be `@objc` since selectors 
after swift 3+ are a must to add that and add the button as param into it:

```
@objc private func deleting(_ button:UIButton){

    // here you got the object
    let selectedObject = JSONList[button.tag]

}
```

Comment: In JSONList[button.tag] its getting Use of unresolved identifier 'button'

Comment: add this deleting(_ button:UIButton)

Comment: its getting Cannot convert value of type 'UIButton.Type' to expected argument type 'UIButton'

Answer (score 0):

use closure to get the tapped buttons cells indexpath.

update the table view cell with ibaction and call the closure whenever tapping on trash button.

```
class FakeTableCell: UITableViewCell{

  var selectedCell: ((UITableViewCell) -> ())?

  @IBAction func trashButtonTapped(){
    selectedCell?(self)
  }
}
```

then we can get the indexpath of the cell in cell for row for indexpath as follows

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = FakeTableCell()
    cell.selectedCell = { selectedCell in
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: selectedCell.center){
            self.deleteData(with: ip.row)
        }
    }
    return cell
}


 func deleteData(with row: Int){
    // get the object by JSONList[row]
    let item = JSONList[row]
    // perform deletion
}
```

Comment: bro its not work can u please write code same like me